# go 1.11.2 xml unexpected EOF

Tags: xml, go

I want to check if an submitted xml file is a valid xml or not so I check if it can be parsed. I do it like that:

```
const EmptyXml = `<?xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"?>`

func CanParse(xmlData string) (bool, error) {
    if strings.TrimSpace(xmlData) == "" {
        return false, nil
    }
    type Tag struct {
        XMLName xml.Name
        Content string `xml:",innerxml"`
    }
    type Object struct {
        Items []Tag `xml:",any"`
    }
    var o *Object
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &o)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    } else {
        return true, nil
    }
}
```

Sadly I end up with an error: unexpected EOF.
Why is this?

Actually the method did work a month ago, and golang has not been updated since then so I´m still about to figure out what broke the method

https://goplay.space/#YxiyTbq8ww0

Comment: So no change of the XML and no change of the binaries, but change of the behavior?

Comment: The error is correct, it's invalid XML because there is an open tag with no closing tag. The incorrect behavior would be the behavior you say used to happen, which I've never witnessed, and which is impossible to troubleshoot if it's not happening now.

Comment: But an empty string causes also an EOF error: https://play.golang.org/p/xJYLK5xVpr9
I would say this is ok, because if I call Unmarshal I would expect something I could unmarshal. But if I try to do this with an empty string that error is ok. Now it is your part to handle that error gracefully

Comment: Ok, with data the error is gone: https://goplay.space/#fnhN563zJLG

Comment: ..but the test does not make any sense now, since it also passes on arbitrary String like "Lore Ipsum": https://goplay.space/#MQxLYMEqiJX

Answer (score 1):

It means that it expected an end tag. I've not done much XML recently, however I think you either have to add a closing `</xml>` or add question marks: `<?xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"?>`

Comment: I think the XML declaration suggestion is not valid (e.g. because of a missing "verison" attribute) although I agree a closing tag is the correct fix here.

Comment: I think the error is ok. Because the umarshaler expects input, but if there is no input that is an error. 
Closing a the Declaration is not a good idea. I would say that this could cause a lot of problems with other xml programs.

Comment: actually i have tried your suggestions, also with <?xml version="1.0"?> (which has been working for sure until now, but it also ends up with the same error, which confuses me. I don´t need the xml to contain data, it just need to be valid.

Comment: How ever as @apxp suggested, its up to me now obviously to handle the error because with some data the error is gone: https://goplay.space/#fnhN563zJLG

Comment: Here is a solution with EOF handling: https://goplay.space/#2x1640wtT7_l

Comment: Sorry, I had to revert the optimism. I turned out that is also passing now on creap, which is not even xml like "Lore Ipsum": https://goplay.space/#MQxLYMEqiJX